# что не так с кодом в javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
fucntion humanSayHello(user); {
    console.log('hello ' + user + '!');
};

humanSayHello(varName);
```

Comment: Переменная, которую вы передаете как параметр у вас `undefined`. И `;` после `function` лишняя.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function humanSayHello(user); {//неправильно написано function было
    console.log('hello ' + user + '!') ;
}//; не надо


humanSayHello('Name');
```

Comment: (user); а тут разве ; нужно?